# Sprite Animation using a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, for-loop, sprite

I am trying to create an animation using a sprite sheet and a for loop to manipulate the background position until it has reached the total number or rows in the sheet. Ideally a reset back to the initial position would be practical, but I cannot even get the animation itself to trigger...

With the current function, no errors occur and the background position in my CSS does not change. I even recorded using Chrome DevTools Timeline and there was nothing either then everything related to my page loading. I have also tried using "background-position-y" as well as a simpler value rather then the math I currently have in place.

This is my function:

```
$(document).load(function() {
    var $height= 324;
    var $rows= 34;
    for(var i=0; i<$rows; i++){
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#selector').css("background-position", "0px ", "0" - ($height*i) + "px");
        }, 10);
    }
});
```

I hate to ask a question that is similar to previous issues, but I cannot seem to find another individual attempting sprite sheet animation with a for loop, so I suppose it is it's own problem.

p.s. I didn't include a snippet of my HTML and CSS because it is pretty standard and I don't see how that could be the problem. That being said, I am all ears to any potential thoughts!

Comment: Use `$(window).load();` since `$(document).load();` is not a valid function

Comment: you are putting ',' outside of string in .css so it will throw error :/

Comment: I updated my answer...I put the explanation in comments for each step :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am completely revamping my answer
This issue is that the `for()` loop is not affected by the `setTimeout` so the function needs to be written on our own terms, not with a `loop`

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TUV9f/2/)

Here it is..

```
var $height= 5;
var $rows= 25;
var i = 1; // Starting Point

(function animateMe(i){
    if(i<=$rows){ // Test if var i is less than or equal to number of rows
        var newHeight = 0-($height*i)+"px"; // Creat New Height Position
        console.log(i); //Testing Purposes - You can Delete
        $('#selector').css({"background-position": "0px "+ newHeight}); // Set New Position
        i++; // Increment by 1 (For Loop Replacement)  
        setTimeout(function(){animateMe(i)}, 1000);  // Wait 1 Second then Trigger Function 
    };
})(0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate your newHeight variable addition! keeps everything way more organized! Although, I am experiencing an issue still. Please refer to above.

Comment: above being the comments to Krunals suggestion. This time I am actually going to work!

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly! I have one more question if you don't mind. What is the significance  of the (0) at the end?

Comment: That actually just triggers the function for the first time. It's an alternative to writing a `function myFunction(){}` and then triggering the function like `myFunction();`

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution

First Change

```
 $(document).load() To $(document).ready()
```

And Change .css Syntex as

```
$('#selector').css("background-position",'0px '+(0 - ($height*i))+'px');
```

Here is fiddle Check it ihad implemented it on my recent project http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/7HSFH/

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: I agree with Krunal, I would go a step further and do all your calculations outside of the `.css()` then insert the variables into the `.css()`

Comment: Dude check my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/7HSFH/
If you can't understand it let me know i will help you dude :)

Comment: Looks like he took the answer and ran ;)

Comment: hey guys! sorry for the delayed response, I had to go to bed due to work this morning! I am going to go back at it again once I am done for the day! I just wanted to say thanks so you didn't think that I just bailed..

Comment: I quickly threw in your suggested edit and the function now works! only issue is that it jumps all the way to end.. Does the for loop need to be nested in a setTimeout to give it a delay as well???

Comment: Hey Krunal and @VIDesignz (I think I did that right?), The function is now working but it has an odd bug.

It waits the amount of milliseconds set and then applies background-position: 0px -10692px; This is row 33 in my sprite sheet as well as 324x33. It does not go through any of the other rows/frames in the sprite sheet, the loop is essentially working as a delayed change of a css rule.